# How to use java objects instead of string to handle a multipart requests on server side for 'application/json' and 'application/vnd.3gpp.5gnas'

Tags: spring-boot, multipart

Client to Sever Using String in RequestBody works fine.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/createSessions",
            produces = { "application/json", "multipart/related", "application/problem+json" },
            consumes = { "application/json", "multipart/related","multipart/mixed"})
    public ResponseEntity<SessionData> testSessions(Request jettyRequest, Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaderMap, @RequestBody String sessionCreateDataMultiPart) {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(multipartData, "multipart/related"));
            for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
                log.info("MultiPart: ", bodyPart);
                log.info("MultiParts: ", bodyPart);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client to Sever Using Java Object in RequestPart not able to parse.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/createSessions",
            produces = { "application/json", "multipart/related", "application/problem+json" },
            consumes = { "application/json", "multipart/related","multipart/mixed"})
    public ResponseEntity<SessionData> testSessions(Request jettyRequest, Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaderMap, @RequestPart SessionCreateDataMultiPart sessionCreateDataMultiPart) {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(multipartData, "multipart/related"));
            for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
                log.info("MultiPart: ", bodyPart);
                log.info("MultiParts: ", bodyPart);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will need to handle this yourself and disable the multipart support in Spring. This isn't supported by the default multipart support.